# CSS fit-content not working with Microsoft-Edge

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, webkit, microsoft-edge

I should align button and text to one line somewhere on the screen, and it is now working everywhere except Microsoft Edge.

I tried to place the text "Not received an SMS code?" to be at the bottom-left corner of the button:

```
<div className="button-group">
    <input
          type="submit"
          className="form-button"
          value="Login" />
     <span className="link">Not received an SMS code?</span>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Edge does not currently support CSS's `fit-content`.

https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content

> Edge 12 - 17: Not Supported
>   Edge 18: Not Supported

It is being supported in Edge 75, which is the first version to use the Chromium rendering engine instead of EdgeHTML. It is currently only available as a dev preview download.